# Código que se repite demasiadas veces

Tags: python, jupyter

Tengo el siguiente código que utilizo para generar unos mapas sin embargo considero que es demasiado repetitivo y que debe de haber alguna forma de hacerlo mas eficiente considerando, que este se repite n veces con diferentes nombres.

```
os.mkdir('Mapas/Nacional')
shpnac = gpd.read_file('Shapes/Nacional/Estatal.shp')
shpnac.set_index('NOM_ENT', inplace=True)




#Nacional
#1 Homicidio doloso *
try:
    nacHD = shpnac.join(nacTdol)
    nacHD1 = nacHD.plot(column='TDoloso18', cmap='YlGn', scheme='equal_interval', legend=True,
                            legend_kwds={'bbox_to_anchor':(0.5,-0.1),'loc':9,'ncol':2,'facecolor':'None', 'edgecolor':'None'},
                            linewidth=0.5, edgecolor='k', facecolor=None)
    nacHD1.set_title('Homicidio Doloso, Nacional, 2019')
    nacHD1.axis('off')


    HDpltnac = nacHD1.get_figure()
    HDpltnac.savefig("Mapas/Nacional/nacHdol.png", dpi=400,bbox_inches='tight',frameon=False,transparent=True)
except:
    pass


#2 Homicidio culposo *
try:
    nacHC = shpnac.join(nacCul)
    nacHC1 = nacHC.plot(column='Culposo18', cmap='YlGn', scheme='equal_interval', legend=True,
                            legend_kwds={'bbox_to_anchor':(0.5,-0.1),'loc':9,'ncol':2,'facecolor':'None', 'edgecolor':'None'},
                            linewidth=0.5, edgecolor='k', facecolor=None)
    nacHC1.set_title('Homicidio Culposo, Nacional, 2019')
    nacHC1.axis('off')

    HCpltnac = nacHC1.get_figure()
    HCpltnac.savefig("Mapas/Nacional/nacHcul.png", dpi=400,bbox_inches='tight',frameon=False,transparent=True)
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Mira qué parte es idéntica y cuál diferente en los trozos que se repiten. Copia todo ese código a una función, y haz que reciba como parámetros la parte que es diferente. Llama a la función dos veces con diferentes parámetros.

Es decir:

```
def genera_grafica(df, columna, titulo, fichero, carpeta="Mapas/Nacional"):
    try:
        nac = shpnac.join(df)
        nac1 = nac.plot(column=columna, cmap='YlGn', scheme='equal_interval',
                        legend=True,
                        legend_kwds={'bbox_to_anchor':(0.5,-0.1),'loc':9,
                                    'ncol':2,'facecolor':'None',
                                    'edgecolor':'None'},
                        linewidth=0.5, edgecolor='k', facecolor=None)
        nac1.set_title(titulo)
        nac1.axis('off')
        pltnac = nac1.get_figure()
        pltnac.savefig(carpeta + "/" + fichero, dpi=400,bbox_inches='tight',
                    frameon=False,transparent=True)
    except:
        pass

os.mkdir('Mapas/Nacional')
shpnac = gpd.read_file('Shapes/Nacional/Estatal.shp')
shpnac.set_index('NOM_ENT', inplace=True)

# ...

genera_grafica(nacTdol, 'TDoloso18',
              'Homicidio Doloso, Nacional, 2019', "nacHdol.png")
genera_grafica(nacCul, 'Culposo18',
               'Homicidio Culposo, Nacional, 2019', "nacHcul.png")
```

Si tienes que llamarla más veces, puedes preparar una lista de tuplas con los parámetros que haya que pasar en cada llamada, e iterar en un bucle para hacer esas llamadas sin tener que repetir código. Es decir:

```
parametros = [
    (nacTdol, 'TDoloso18', 'Homicidio Doloso, Nacional, 2019', "nacHdol.png"),
    (nacCul, 'Culposo18', 'Homicidio Culposo, Nacional, 2019', "nacHcul.png")
]

for caso in parametros:
    genera_grafica(*caso)
```